# Ternary Operator in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I was trying to simply the if operator by using Ternary Operator in Laravel 8 and end up the error shown blow

```
syntax error, unexpected token "="
```

Below is the piece of code I have :

```
{{ $title === "New Member" ? value="{{$data->full_name}}" : value="{{$data->name}}" }}
```

Please help me to fix that error.

Comment: `value="{{ $title === 'New Member' ? $data->full_name : $data->name }}"` would be the correct syntax; `{{ }}` starts a PHP blade template line, using multiple `{{ ... {{ ... }} }}` doesn't make any syntactical sense.

Comment: you can use @ php your code @ endphp

Answer (score 0):

You have to many curly braces in your code, instead try this:

```php
{{ $title === "New Member" ? $data->full_name : $data->name }}
```

This outputs the full name when the title is `New Member`, and the name otherwise.

Infact, the double curly braces in Blade are for displaying data, not exactly for assigning variables. For this, you should use the `@php` directive as so:

```php
@php
  $value = ( $title === "New Member" ? $data->full_name : $data->name );
@endphp

// output it

{{ $value }}
```

*Note: The parenthesis are not required, but make the code more readable.*